# How to display a compessed Blob file from mySQL DB with php

Tags: java, php, mysql, web

I have written an Android app which sends images to my mySQL database. Before sending the image to db i compress it for less traffic:

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

So now I want to display the image at my website using php. I tried it with not compressed images and it worked with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db-name"); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_images WHERE id = $id";
    $sth = $db->query($sql);
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['imgdata']     ).'"/>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me with the compressed image? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) any gains you'll get from compressing your image will be lost by base64 encoding it. Best to keep your image as binary and upload it.

2) It is preferable to store files on the file system instead of storing a base64 encoded string in the database. So you'll store a filename or file path in the database record and the actual binary on the file system. Then in the image tag, you'll just make the source be the path to the uploaded file.

3) Your SQL query is open to SQL injection. What would the query return if I typed my id parameter as "1 OR 1=1"?